# Swinject: generate instances of any object (for not registered object, ViewModel, etc...)

Tags: swift, dependency-resolver, swinject

is possible to resolve/ create a new instace of object thats are not registered in Swinject container? In Unity dependency injection for c# (from Microsoft) is it.

I Want to resolve viewModel class, that have dependence for some protocols.
For example:
I have registred IFileManager in container:

```
container.register(IFileManager.self) { _ in FileManager() }.inObjectScope(ObjectScope.container)
```

and me viewModel have dependece for IFileManager

```
class AwesomeViewModel{
init (fileManager: IFileManager) {
    ....
}}
```

now i want to create new instance of AwesomeViewModel using Swinject resolver, and I want all the dependencies to be added to the init, but it doesn't work

```
viewModel = AppDelegate.container.resolve(AwesomeViewModel.self)
```

and ViewModel is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Swinject is not able to infer which initialisation method you expect to be used for instantiation of `AwesomeViewModel`. You need to explicitly define it first:

```
container.register(AwesomeViewModel.self) {
    AwesomeViewModel(fileManager: $0.resolve(IFileManager.self)!)
}
```

Admittedly, this might get quite cumbersome if you have classes with many dependencies. If that becomes a problem, I suggest you check out the [SwinjectAutoregistration](https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectAutoregistration) extension. It enables you to write:

```
container.autoregister(AwesomeViewModel.self, initializer: AwesomeViewModel.init)
```